# How to save a MASK RCNN model after training?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am using matterport repository to train MASK RCNN on a custom dataset. I have been successful in training. Now I want to save the trained model and use it in a web application to detect objects. How do I save the mask rcnn model after training? Please guide me.

The link of the repository:

https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

Comment: Are you looking for the saved weights or the model architecture after training ?

Comment: model architecture

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1299), it appears that trained model or weights of *matterport/Mask RCNN* can be saved as a JSON file in a manner similar to those trained via standard *Keras*:

```
import keras
import json

def save_model(trained_model, out_fname="model.json"):
    jsonObj = trained_model.keras_model.to_json()
    with open(out_fname, "w") as fh:
        fj.write(jsonObj)
 
save_model(model, "mymodel.json")
```

**Update:** If you run into the error related to thread-like object, you might find [this post](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1126) helpful...

Answer (score 0):

In the [Inspect_model.ipynb](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/coco/inspect_model.ipynb) notebook under the "Load Model" topic you can save it after it loads the model in inference mode.

Answer (score 0):

in the folder Mask_RCNN/logs generates a folder inside it

Comment: The OP asked how to save the model arch, not weights. Your answer is true for in the case of saving weights at every epoch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we really need to save the whole model again since normally when we used the matterport git we just train new weights on the existing architecture and doesnt make changes to the architecture. When we used this for a pet project , post training - we defined a new model as the MASK RCNN object (from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN) with the parameter mode as inference and then loaded the newly trained weights model.load_weights('<logpath/trainedweights.h5>', by_name=True)